# can somebody prove $ a^{\log(a)^x} = x$

Tags: logarithms

can somebody please prove that  $$ a^{\log(a)^x} = x$$

it is written in my text book but I cant seem to get it

Some examples if possible

Comment: Did you mean $a^{\log_a x}= x$?

Comment: Should we read $\log(a^x)$ or $(\log(a))^x$ ?

Comment: @StubbornAtom yes

Comment: ${\log_a x}= m\Leftrightarrow a^m=x$ (assuming $x>0,a\ne1,a>0$).

Answer (score 0):

Start with the definition of $b = \log_{a}x \implies x=a^{b} \implies \ln x = b\ln a$

Then let $c = a^b =a^{\log_{a}x}$

Then $\ln c = \ln(a^{b}) = b\ln a$

Note that $\ln x = b\ln a$. Then by comparison, it follows that $c=x = a^{\log_{a}x}$ as required

Or you could think of it in words. $\log_{a}x$ means "the power of $a$ such that $a$ raised to that power equals $x$".

Then $a^{\log_{a}x}$ can be thought of as:    "$a$ to the power of (the power of $a$ that gives $x$)" which must then give $x$

Answer (score 0):

It rather depends on what properties of logarithms you wish to use.

For example, with $a \gt 0$ and $a \not = 1$,

$f(y)=a^y$ and $g(x)=\log_a x$ are inverse bijective functions, with $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^+$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}$

so $f(g(x))=x$, which means  $a^{\log_a x} = x$

---

Alternatively, using natural logarithms,

$\log_a x= \frac{\log_e x}{\log_e a}$  and $a^y= e^{y \log_e a}$

so $a^{\log_a x}= e^{(\log_a x)(\log_e a)} = e^{\log_e x} = x$